# the mongodb database doesn't exist after using `lb4 datasource` to create a database connection in loopback4

Tags: mongodb, loopback4

I have use loopback4 to get an database connection with mongoDB datasource.

I expect after I created the data source,then the datasource will exist in the mongoDB.

this is my datasource file as follows:

```js
const config = {
  name: 'echo3D2',
  connector: 'mongodb',
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/echo3D2',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'echo3D2',
  useNewUrlParser: true
};
```

I think that means I have being successful in creating a database in MongoDB,which name is echo3D2.

then when I check whether the database exist or not,I found **the `echo3D2`database does not exist in MongoDB**. as the follow show in mongoDB CLI

**input**:

```
db.getMongo().getDBNames().indexOf("echo3D2");
```

**output**

```
-1
```

there must be something wrong with it !

what should I do to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

there are something wrong with my operation of creating a database,so I can't connect the mongoDB server，and mongoDB can't create the new database.

the point is I didn't set a primary key for any model in database, so it can't create the database by loopback4.